# Finish for rustic natural kitchen table

Tags: wood, table

this is a picture of my kitchen table and coffee table. Both are sanded down to only wood. We like the rustic non shine look and the color exactly like it is but need some coating for use. What is the best coating that will keep this color and not add a shine or gloss? ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cvCY.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: clear matte finish acrylic is your best bet: waterproof, tough, and non-yellowing

Comment: @dandavis would Minwax Polycrylic clear matte  water based work? Can't find acrylic...

Comment: that sounds like it has some polyerethane, which is what yellows. The stuff you want is, for lack of better term, "spray paint". I find rustoleaum pro to have a nice nozzle that makes it easier to get a good finish, but the chemicals are the same as a store bought clear coat. any spray matte acrylic "paint" will work, and you can get pints of the same instead of spray cans if you want to brush.